# How to open a URL on the web platform in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my code which opens a URL in the new tab when the user clicks on the button, but I want to open the URL in a dialog on the same page, not in the new tab.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:flutter_learnings2/other_work/in_app_web.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'dart:html' as html;

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    home: WebViewScreen(),
  ));
}

class WebViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewScreen> createState() => _WebViewScreenState();
}

class _WebViewScreenState extends State<WebViewScreen> {
  final url =
      "https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=858410514048&forceauthn=false";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: kIsWeb ? const Text("This is Web") : const Text("This is IOS"),
        ),
        body: kIsWeb
            ? Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        webSpecificFunction2();
                      },
                      child: const Text("Click")),
                ),
              )
            : const MyWebApp());
  }

  void mobileSpecificFunction() {
    print("Executing web specific function");
  }
  void webSpecificFunction2() {
    print("Executing the web specific function");

    // Open the URL in a new window
    html.window.open(url, 'Google Authentication');
  }

}
```

I have also tried using `InAppWebView` and `webview_flutter`, but these libraries don't support web platforms.

Can anyone please help me to open the URL in the dialog on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

To display a webpage inside a dialogue box web, create an `IFrameElement` using the `html` package and use `ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory` to show it.
`onError` helps handle exceptions in cases where the URL can’t be loaded.

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:ui_web' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Create an IFrameElement
    final IFrameElement iFrameElement = IFrameElement();

    // Set the src of the IFrameElement to the URL you want to load
    iFrameElement.src = 'https://flutter.dev';
    iFrameElement.style.border = 'none';
    iFrameElement.style.width = '100%';
    iFrameElement.style.height = '100%';

    // Register the IFrameElement
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'webview',
      (int viewId) => iFrameElement,
    );

    return MaterialApp(home: MyHomePage());
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView in Dialog'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => Dialog(
              child: Container(
                child: HtmlElementView(
                  viewType: 'webview',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Text('Open Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

output : [image]

Comment: In your code, I am getting width and height related issues:

`Height of Platform View type: [webview] may not be set. Defaulting to `height: 100%`.`

`Width of Platform View type: [webview] may not be set. Defaulting to `width: 100%`.`

Comment: @SaurabhJain Jain Now check the code; I made a few changes.

Comment: Your code is working fine only if I use this link: `https://flutter.dev`. When I try to use any other link for ex: `https://www.google.com`, it doesn't work. please help me a bit more. However, thank you for the code!

Comment: @SaurabhJain  The issue you’re encountering is related to the `X-Frame-Options HTTP` response header. This header is used by a website to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `<frame>`, `<iframe>`, or `<object>`
In your case, it seems that `https://www.google.com` has set the `X-Frame-Options` to `SAMEORIGIN` or `DENY`, which means it’s refusing to be embedded in an iframe on a different origin

Comment: So, how can I resolve this issue? Actually, I'll only use a single link, not multiple links and this is the link that I'll use: `https://accounts.google.com/o/saml2/initsso?idpid=C02qtgmcd&spid=858410514048&forceauthn=false`

Comment: If you’re trying to embed a `Google sign-in page`, you might want to consider using a dedicated `sign-in SDK` or `library` that is designed for use in applications, as these pages may have additional restrictions to prevent them from being embedded in `iframes`. For Flutter, the `Google Sign` In package might be a suitable alternative.

OR 

try this  :
          
`onPressed: () {html.window.open(url, 'Google Authentication', 'popup'); },`

Comment: Hi @AkhilGeorge, do you have any Idea, on how to integrate `SAML` authentication in Flutter?